# Cancel AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to cancel an `Asynctask` in android but I have a problem with my implementation :

My code is :

private class SynchroTask extends AsyncTask{
        private volatile boolean running = true;

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //INITIALIZATIONS
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (running) {
            //TASK
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(){
        super.onCancelled();
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent intent = AccountAddActivity.getIntent(getActivity());
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And :

```
mSynchroTask = new SynchroTask();


cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSynchroTask != null && mSynchroTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                    HDCApplication.hdcAppManager.mSynchroManager.removeAllTask();
                    mSynchroTask.cancel(true);
                    mSynchroTask = null;

                }   
            }

        });
```

Comment: the "problem" is with HDCApplication.hdcAppManager.mSynchroManager.removeAllTask();

Comment: when i do : 
mSynchroTask.cancel(true);

I never pass in the onCancelled

Comment: working example on correct way to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

That's half of implementation of what you have done

```
   mSynchroTask.cancel(true);
```

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after
>   doInBackground(Object[]) returns.

This is what you are missing

> To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: oh thank you, How to test the value of isCancelled periodically in the doinbackground

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mSynchroTask != null && mSynchroTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                mSynchroTask.cancel(true);
                mSynchroTask = null;

                HDCApplication.hdcAppManager.mSynchroManager.removeAllTask();

            }
```