# Press "Back" to stop thread when there are a dialog box

Tags: android, dialog

In my program, I start a thread and the progress dialog in the same time. I want to stop the thread after I pressed "Back". But the program only stop my dialog box. I tried in my following code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (runner != null)
            stopThread();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (runner != null)
        stopThread();
}
```

The result is I can only stop the thread when there are no any dialog box is still working, how can I "select" the back action or how can I stop the thread when the same time that dialog box dismiss?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253226/cancel-asynctask-in-android/12253336#12253336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnCancelListener` for the Dialog or if its a custom dialog then Override `OnBackPressed` and then stop the thread inside the method.

Comment: Finally, I used `setOnCancelListener`. Easy handled. Many thanks.